# downloading mp4 video with ffmpeg produces error

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to download a mp4 video from a url using ffmpeg.

Here is my command:

`/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i 'https://hw16.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/249306bba122103d1be6c98f53c4ce5e14166523-720p__77667.mp4' '/home/example/public_html/test/mycron/videos/5c8e7ec5c722b.mp4'`

I attempted but get this error **Error opening filters!**

I tried this command also: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i 'https://hw16.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/249306bba122103d1be6c98f53c4ce5e14166523-720p__77667.mp4' -c:v libx264 -c:a copy '/home/example/public_html/test/mycron/videos/5c8e7ec5c722b.mp4'`

And get this error:  **Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height**

how do i solve?

Comment: Works for me. Show the complete log from either of the commands.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just *download* a video, then `ffmpeg` is overkill. Just use `wget` or `curl`.

You'd use `ffmpeg` if you wanted to transcode/-plex the video into a different codec/file-format during download. And for that you'd give a set of reasonable codec/bitrate parameters, i.e. at least `-c:v`, `-b:v`, `-c:a`, `-b:a` and `-f` parameters (see the `ffmpeg` manual for their meaning).

If you want to download a stream URL  (rtmp or similar), then `rtmpdump` is the right tool; or `youtube-dl` if it's from a popular streaming site (it supports YouTube, Vimeo, MyVideo, … effectively every streaming site out there).